# select questions which doesnot have answers

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have a simple query doubt.

```
Question Table
qid question
1   ques1
2   ques2
3   ques3
4   ques4
5   ques5
6   ques6
7   ques7

Answer Table
ansid qid answer
1     1   ans1
2     2   ans2
3     2   ans3
4     4   ans4
5     6   ans5
```

I have two tables. One for questions and one for answers. Question id(qid) is use as a foreign key in answer table. I want select questions which doesnot have an answer in the answer table. In the above example I need questions 3,5,7. My database is large it may contain more than 50,000 records.

Thanks
ARun

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: You may need an OUTER JOIN http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select q.* from question as q
left join answer as a
on q.id = a.qid
where a.qid is null
```

edit.
Moreover it would be better to add an index on answer table

```
alter table answer add index iq (qid);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from question where qid not in 
(select qid from answer)
```

Comment: Now am using this query. It giving me correct answer. Is there any performance issue if I use this one. 
SELECT question 
FROM tbl_question q
LEFT JOIN tbl_answer a ON q.id=a.qid 
WHERE a.qid IS NULL

Comment: @user504383 - Guess this is classical case of subquery vs joins. In your case, I am sure the performance difference would be negligible.

Comment: @nick rulez, re NOT IN could you provide some references? For example like this (that explains why and when NOT IN is the same as LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL in mysql): http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Hi Sachin Shanbhag. I know that blog. it's my favourite one. :) As soon as I can I'll made a stored procedure to populate tables with enough large dataset and I'll post resuls. For my experience subquery with in (especially with mysql < 5.5) run slower than using left join

Comment: @nick - Dont worry. Its for OP to decide. As for mysql, I think performance will come only when there are records that count in millions. Thats why I said, in this case, it should be negligible. Anyway, OP has made his choice neverthless :)